# ASP.NET Core 3.0 endpoint routing and custom middlewares

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

What is the replacement of this code in .NET 3.0 with endpoint routing?

```cs
app.UseRouter(a => a.MapMiddlewareGet(
    "middleware1",
    b => b.UseMiddleware<Middleware1>()));
```

or should it be left like this:

```
app.UseRouter(a => a.MapMiddlewareGet(
    "middleware1",
    b => b.UseMiddleware<Middleware1>()));
app.UseEndpoints(a => a.MapControllers());
```

Comment: I'd love to know this too, the docs are a mess and still use the now deprecated syntax almost everywhere for the 3.0 docs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code helps you. I have tested and it is working.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    var newAppbuilder = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder();
    newAppbuilder.UseMiddleware<Middleware1>();

    endpoints.MapGet("middleware1", newAppbuilder.Build());
});
```

Comment: I have created issue in aspnetcore github. You can support for feature request. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14514